# How to display images in circular transform using glide v4 in android

Tags: android, android-glide

How to display an image in circular transform in android using glide v4.
I am trying to display the image in circular transform in an image view using glide v4 in android using the following code

```
RequestOptions options=new RequestOptions();
Glide.with(this).load(urlProfileImg)
                .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imgProfile);
```

I am not sure whether to use **this** or **context**
If I have to use context, someone please suggest me how to get the context and how to make the images displayed in circular form using glide v4 in android

Comment: Just change `RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()` to `options.circleCropTransform()`

Comment: It's not working, had tried doing that earlier also

Comment: Actually, I discovered, the issue is that, the image is located on a private server which doesn't has a Security Certificate. Any help on that would be highly appreciated